# Recovering added/staged file after doing git reset --hard HEAD^?

Tags: git, version-control, recovery

I added a new file `F1` and made changes to another file F2 but then did a `git reset --hard HEAD^` and I have lost all the changes to the files.

Is there *some* way, I can get them back?

I did look at a related question here: [How can I undo git reset --hard HEAD~1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1)  but, that question assumes that the one has done a Git commit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo git reset --hard with uncommitted files in the staging area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374069/undo-git-reset-hard-with-uncommitted-files-in-the-staging-area)

Comment: Now there is a git script that does this out of the box: https://github.com/pendashteh/git-recover-index

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You can (with some work) recover state of file at the last "git add *<file>*". You can use

```
$ git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --dangling HEAD
```

and then examine files in '.git/lost-found/other' directory.

Please read [git fsck](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fsck.html) manpage.

Comment: `git show -p --format=raw $blob > $blob.txt` +1, saved my life.

Comment: It seems that on git 1.9.1, --unreachable causes .git/lost-found to not be created

Comment: As stated --unreachable prevents creation of ".git/lost-found". I made it work using the following instead
$ git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --dangling HEAD

Comment: this appears to have worked but i lost all the file extensions?

Comment: Sorry, once I recovered the blob files, what to do next?

Comment: @AlfredoCastanedaGarcia: after recovering contents of files, save it as a file (under the filename you choose), either copying from `.git/lost-found/other`, or redirecting output of `git cat-file -p <sha-1>` / `git show <sha-1>`. HTH.

Comment: Totally saved my life! I needed to remove the --unreachable flag though as @JacobT.Nielsen mentioned. Once done, I had to grep all the files in .git/lost-found/other for a string I recognised in the lost file.

Comment: +1 Worked for me as well. Before I absent mindedly did Undo Changes, I had thankfully staged all the changes (that too by mistake). I used Notepad++ and its terrific feature to Find in Files, my relevant code bits.

Answer (score 46):

(I'm assuming that the missing file is *not* part of any commit. Otherwise, `git log --all -g --diff-filter=D --stat` is your friend.)

1. Get list of unreachable files that `git` knows a file name:

   ```
   git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs --no-cache HEAD | fgrep " tree " \
   | cut -d " " -f3 | xargs -r -n1 git ls-tree \
   | fgrep " blob " | cut -d " " -f 3- | sort -k2 -u
   ```
2. If you see something interesting, `git cat-file blob SHA-1-of-interesting-file` will  output the file to standard output. (Example: `git cat-file blob b8f0bdf56 > recovered-logo.png`)

Unfortunately, if the missing file is not part of the any commit, git does not have a timestamp and as such, you cannot print various versions of files ordered by time.

If the missing file has never been staged (`git stage` or `git add`) or stashed (`git stash`), you're pretty much out of luck because as far as git knows, the file never did exist. (You may still try doing a `git fsck --no-reflogs --lost-found` and looking around in directory `.git/lost-found/other` to see if you have anything worth keeping in case git indeed has a copy of your missing file by some lucky accident. You do not have file names to help you in this case, only file contents.)

In case you just lost some commits (instead of just files), you'll probably want to run something like this:

```
gitk --all $( git fsck | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}'; git log -g --pretty='format:%H' )
```

That will run `gitk` with all the branches, all the reflog and all the dangling commits. You may want to add `-n 10000` or some other limit in case your repo has really many commits (say linux kernel). If you do not have `gitk`, you may instead run lesser version using only command line like this:

```
git log --all --decorate --stat --graph --date-order $( git fsck | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}'; git log -g --pretty='format:%H' )
```

or a version with less verbose output

```
git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph --date-order $( git fsck | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}'; git log -g --pretty='format:%H' )
```

If you see some commit you want to save as branch `recovered1`, simply do `git checkout -b recovered1 <sha1-of-the-commit>`.

Comment: Wow! just found an untracked file, which got accidentally discarded by me (without even committing it), using `git fsck --no-reflogs --lost-found` and then searching it inside the directory `.git/lost-found/other` (with _Notepade++_'s _Find in Files_ search). Thank you!

Comment: I have to add that I seriously recommend doing automated versioned backups over trying to recover files from git history.

Comment: omg thank you! @Ofir, the same worked for me!! "$ git fsck --no-reflogs --lost-found" then search through files in ".git/lost-found/other"

Answer (score 7):

Try this http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html

I got a heart attack for the changes I lost. But after following this post. I got my changes back

Comment: You wel come :) Glad it helped.

Comment: This answer just saved me 6 years later, THANKS !

Answer (score 6):

There is a `git plugin` that does this out of the box:

https://github.com/pendashteh/git-recover-index

```
$ cd /path/to/disatered/repo
$ git clone git@github.com:pendashteh/git-recover-index.git $HOME/.git-recover-index
$ $HOME/.git-recover-index/git-recover-index.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you've added the object to the index (by using git add), there is a blob created for that state of the object - but there is no tree (and thus, commit) object that is referring to it. This is how one gets a 'dangling' loose object file, and if you run git fsck it will show you the unreferenced blob (git gc will delete these types of objects if it is run).

Because of this, you can use the reflog, if you have it enabled, to try and restore the index state for your file F1 that has been added. If you haven't added F2 at all, then as Greg said, git doesn't know anything about it and you're out of luck there.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the VSCode, you can use the Timelime feature (by clicking right button mouse on changed file and choose "Open Timeline")