# VSCode "Discard all changes" any ways/list of ways to recover (even via system image)

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code

I suffer from dyslexia and have been working on several projects. I clicked on the "Discard all changes" button after reading it incorrectly. From this point it removed several University projects (not backed up at my misfortune).

I have contacted Apple's 24/7 accessibility line thus far to speak about this and they have directed me here. I want to ask if any one has come across this issue. If so suggestions or fixes for this are welcone. I record my entire study processes as it enables me to refer back. However in this case I did not dackup the immediate work which I was working on.

I am extremely worried because this work is due tomorrow and it has removed everything! (from graphs, tables and other files)

You can imagine with my disability that this takes me some extra time to complete and would like to thank any information given in advance and hope any new findings helps others in the future.

I have attached a reference point which apple has told me to check out and politely went through with me (however they suggested to still post as there technical support hours business hour constraint) Ref: [How do you undo "Discard all changes" in VS Code/Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541167/how-do-you-undo-discard-all-changes-in-vs-code-git)

> ** Quick reference point for suggestions thus far **
>
> Time machine
>
> Future implementations of a better workflow (i.e. frequent backups
>   using git)
>
> Apple have referred me to "Data recovery specialist"
>   http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/services-software/recover/ they indeed
>   charge however you can test the software before you pay. (this has not solved my issue of yet however may help someone else)

Comment: Did you at least stage the changes (`git add`), if that's the case you should be able to go back to a previous state of your working directory through the reflog. (see redo after undo local: https://github.com/blog/2019-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git)

Comment: This is what is currently shown on the source control @jessehouwing https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3xATjpMD2DlSWYzcU9ON1FpRWM

Comment: I sympathize with your problem but unless you have backup of those files they are most likely gone. Not gone in the sense that **impossible** to recover but given your time frame and situation I daresay this is impossible. The files are *probably* still present on the disk, just no longer linked to by the directory structure in which case a disk restoration company could probably restore them, but this would take time and cost an arm and a leg.

Comment: In the future I would take heed to change your workflow process as it seems to be somewhat broken, if you have lost **a lot** of work with 1 discard then it means you follow the "commit only when 100% done" doctrine which is not a good workflow, for many reasons, one of which is the problem you have now. Additionally, if these files are important, backup separate from your version control should also be mandatory. I say this only to guide you to avoid this kind of situation in the future but none of this helps you now I'm afraid.

Comment: Since you're on OS X, do you have a time machine backup set up?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen unfortunately not I am a poor student and don't have the space locally to facilitate this. You can imagine some of the other applications which I have on my mac to support me for accessibility reasons. Are you aware of a way to restore a previous image without using time machine?

Comment: That is the wrong question to ask. This is the right one: Do you **have** a previous image to restore to? Everything you've said so far indicate that you did not commit to git, you do not have a backup, and thus this means you don't have an image. Unfortunately this means that the only way to restore your files is to use a recovery program (or company) specializing in recovering deleted files. Unfortunately there is no guarantee either would be able to help you, and probably/certainly not all your files.

Comment: On the commandline, type 'git reflog'. The IDE doesn't show that.

Comment: @jessehouwing "fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet" is the output

Comment: Then you're in a really really bad state and git can't help you. Nor can vs code.