# How to undo git discard

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I accidentally discarded saved changes to file which is neither committed nor staged. What can i do to recover it?

already tried some random solutions from net but none of them helped me.

Tried 
`git clean -fd`

also tried
`git checkout -- <filename>`

tried  `git checkout -- .` too.

I am using VSCode

Edit: Note: I Discarded changes on few days back and now I came to know I discarded wrong files.

Comment: If you never committed or staged the file, `git` doesn't know anything about it. You won't be able to recover those changes unless you have some sort of system backups available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you undo "Discard all changes" in VS Code/Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541167/how-do-you-undo-discard-all-changes-in-vs-code-git)

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, the question is relevant but tried that solution not worked for me, that file is not in my trash too. 

Note: I Discarded changes on few days back and now I came to know I discarded wrong files.

Comment: Please [edit] to add this information.

Comment: you can use this `git checkout -- .` instead of file name use dot(.) This command discards all.

Comment: @NayanSarder already tried. Updated question.

Comment: Try to use `git restore .`

Comment: for this kind of errors use a hourly/daily (incremental) backup tool of the source code directories. But then hourly is also not covering it all (deleted it 20 min ago). Use a file system with file versions like VMS. Each save you get a new file version.

Answer (score 1):

for Android Studio i managed to get back one by one with local history

```
Choose file or folder -> Local History -> Show History
```

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't closed the editor you can try ctrl + z. Have you?

Comment: as I mentioned in question I discarded few days back after this around 3 times I shut down my PC.