# How to undo a discard changes in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-branch

I'm new to git, I was building a project with couple of branches.
I was in branch B with uncomitted changes and then I run this command:

```
git checkout -b C
```

to move to new branch, let's call it branch C.

In branch C I uncommit those changes and since then I can't get those changes back, even if I go back to branch B.

I'm not sure if I checkout of a branch it's means that it's saved somewhere.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: if you checkout a new branch you take with you the changes made in the files, so there is no way to get them back

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you undo "Discard all changes" in VS Code/Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541167/how-do-you-undo-discard-all-changes-in-vs-code-git)

Comment: What does "I uncommit those changes" mean?

Comment: @matt when i said "uncommit" i meant that i did not commit the changes , so basicly i did nothing before checkout to a new branch

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't track changes you haven't told it to track.

All changes that are uncommitted are just sort of floating.  When you use `checkout` those changes come with you to the new branch.  If you destroy those changes without saving them, they are gone.

If you want to save the changes on a branch to come back to later, you can use [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), this saves the uncommitted changes at the current commit and cleans them away from your current perspective.

Comment: Git doesn't "track changes" _at all_. It stores commits.

Comment: To my knowledge, in git, commits are stored as diffs; or, in common English, they are changes, that are kept track of.

Comment: When was that changed and what does git do nowadays?

Comment: It was never changed. Git has always been about commits, which are snapshots. Might want to see my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/, see the Commits section.

Comment: Thanks, I'm more familiar with git's origins than it's development.  To my recollection git was originally (before it was named) a way of bundling patch files and emailing them.  That was latter changed to ssh; but, the way of thinking about commits as changes from the previous commit does a good job of demystifying how merges, cherry picking, and history modding operations work and behave.

Comment: I disagree. Merges etc do rely on diffs but commits are not diffs. Diffs are derived from comparison of commits; they are not what Git stores. Saying they are does the OP no favors.

Comment: Feel free to edit/improve my wording.  You are clearly more informed on the modern behind the scenes than I.