# Restore last version vscode Git

Tags: git

I have discarded 1.5k changes by mistake, **it's literally 20 days of work**, my last safe version it's 20days ago, pls guys is there's any way so I can get my changes back?

[image]

Comment: "it's literally 20 days of work"—did you really go nearly three weeks without making a commit? I encourage my team to commit multiple times per day.

Comment: In any case, what version of Visual Studio Code are you using? The latest release [includes a local history feature that _might_ be able to help](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_local-history).

Comment: did you change 1500+ files in 20 days, that is a lot of work, and a big project

Comment: I was working alone I know I'm stupid because I didn't expected that (I don't have local history in vsc).

Comment: YEAAAH +1.5k changes, I'm really about to cry because it's my final project for studying and I really put so much energy and time in it, I'll just take a day break and go back to it stronger.

Comment: Did you run `git add` or `git stash` on these files if not `git commit`?

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

VSCode just added this as a new feature: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26339

### Original Answer:

I'm afraid your work is most likely lost. However, if you're lucky, you might be able to **undo** (Ctrl+Z) in the editor.

To see a history of Git commands VSCode has executed, you can open the output console following [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-output-window).

From the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43560079/15271699):

> The Clean All (discard all changes) option in VS code essentially executes:
>
> ```sh
> git clean -fd
> git checkout -- .
> ```
>
> So it is git's hands whether `git clean -fd` can undo discarding uncommitted changes. Unfortunately the changes are not stored in git since it not committed, so after `git clean -fd` is executed, git will remove untracked files by force.
>
> After executing the command `git checkout -- .`, git will checkout all the modified files in git as the version of last commit.

Consider it a lesson learned - remember to commit often. This is exactly why we have version control. If you don't want to pollute your git history, you can create WIP commits, then [rebase](https://dev.to/timwjames/git-techniques-to-undo-your-mistakes-1jl2) to clean up the history before you push to a remote. Alternatively for VSCode, I like to use an extension called [Checkpoints](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=micnil.vscode-checkpoints), which allows you to create checkpoints between commits for a local short-term history of work.

Comment: My last commit was 20 days ago so that won't help, and I gave up on it now I'm starting my project again, and have a nice day man <3