# How can I erase multiple changes in my main git user?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm a bit new at this, so bear with me.

I saved a .js file in my user just so I could run it's output in Terminal. This file appears to have created changes in all my projects. I feel a bit foolish.

How can I discard all these changes at once? I tried doing this in VS Code, but when I click the **Discard All Changes** option, VS Code says that might delete one or more files (see attached screenshot). Naturally, I feel this might be a bad idea.

Then I tried `get reset--hard`, `git checkout -f`, and `git reset --hard HEAD^` on my user through command lines in Terminal, but I always get the same error message:

> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I don't know how to now get around the issue.

You can find images of the problem attached:

[File changes and terminal message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJORn.jpg)

[VS Code message with all files which will be deleted if I discard changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb3eM.jpg)

Thank you in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Might be a time to learn using git from command line. Confusing situations sre sometimes much less confusing when you examine them without an extra GUI layer in between.

Comment: Also, VS Code is a bit [notorious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541167/how-do-you-undo-discard-all-changes-in-vs-code-git) when it comes to using *git* from it...

Comment: Make sure you use the terminal inside the project folder

Comment: just typing random `git` commands and hoping one will do what you want is asking for disaster. `get reset --hard` is a good one if you don't know what you're doing and what the command does, you have a git repo, only you don't know where it is

Comment: Note that `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` means *you are not yet using Git*. You might want to start by experimenting with Git alone (no GUI, as @hyde suggested) on something of no value, by creating an empty folder, moving into it, running `git init`, creating a simple file or two such as "readme" and "main.js", `git add readme main.js`, and `git commit` to make your first commit. Then find a good Git tutorial (unfortunately this is hard, there are a lot of bad ones)...

Comment: at the git-scm site is a good book for download

Comment: I think I now understand the issue a lot better. All y'all have been extraordinarily kind for helping out with this matter. Thank you! I've evidently quite a bit to study and catch up on regarding git.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a Git repository in the `aula-matheus` folder, but you did `cd ..` and went in the parent folder of that repository.

There is no Git repository in that parent folder itself, only in `aula-matheus`: if you want to execute any git command, you need to be in that folder.

Also, you can execute those same operation using VSCode Git integration, and see more with the [VSCode GitLens extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens).