# Git merge branch into master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have a master branch and a working `branch_1`. I want to 'move' `branch_1` exactly as it is to `master`. So I want something like this:

```
git checkout master
git merge branch_1 # I don't know what is correct...
```

Things which I did but I got loads of files messed up with annoying conflicts. So now master contains exactly the same files of `branch_1` avoiding any conflicts, just overwriting files.
Any help?

Comment: One option would be to `git reset --hard branch_1`, but that loose all history in `master` that is not shared with `branch_1`.

Comment: What do you mean by "move" `branch_1` to `master`? Do you just want to do a simple merge? Getting conflicts is not unusual in a merge, so there's nothing special about it. As the question is currently written, it is not clear what the problem is.

Comment: See also: [How to use git merge --squash?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5309051/562769)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge development branch with master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168677/merge-development-branch-with-master)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Conflicts are going to happen if both branches have changes to the files.  This is a good thing.  **Keeping your branches up-to-date with each other will prevent some of them**
.  However over all, conflicts are not bad.  The rebase option can also prevent many of them from happening.

```
git merge branch_1
```

If you are on `master`, merging will bring the changes as you expect.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html

You could also

```
git rebase branch_1
```

This will take the changes from `branch_1` and append them to master without a merge commit.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should not merge?

1. Checkout branch_1
2. Rebase master changes into branch_1
3. Fix any errors that might have occured after testing your code
4. Checkout master
5. Rebase branch_1 changes into master

or in code:

```
git checkout branch_1
git rebase master
(...)
git checkout master
git rebase branch_1
```

This also gives you the opportunity to squash several commits into one, if you want to make your changesets more dense, and prevents these annoying merge-commits in your history.

Answer (score 1):

I took this code from [thenetninja youtube](https://youtu.be/XX-Kct0PfFc) channel and it  works for me.

## on non master branch

```
  git add .
  git commit -m "msg"
  git checkout master
```

## on master branch

```
  git merge <non master branch name>
  # fix any conflicts and try to run the software to test any error
  git add .
  # commit w/o any msg, as follows
  git commit
  git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use git rebase branch_1
This will resolve the conflicts in the other branch while being on master branch.