# How do I push changes I made in a branch into the master branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-repo

There is no remote repository.

There only exist one repository on my local machine.

So here is what I did:

```
git branch new-branch
git checkout new-branch

//implemented some changes

//now wants to push changes to master
//what is the command?
```

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink then who do I get the master branch to reflect the changes made in new-branch?

Comment: If there's no remote, there's no pushing. You just commit the changes to your branch, then merge to master.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git merge branch into master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605231/git-merge-branch-into-master)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I Understand, what you are trying to do is "merge" your branch with master.
so try the following.

```
git branch new-branch
git checkout new-branch

//implemented some changes

//to push chages to master first checkout to master
git checkout master
git merge new-branch
```

Answer (score 1):

It may sound like I'm nitpicking here, but in git (and therefore in the git documentation) what you're saying you want to do is not what "push" means.

What you're trying to do is "merge" your changes into the `master` branch.  Please refer to the `git merge` documentation for an explanation of the basics.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 0):

You're merging your commit to master, not pushing it. Pushing is for sending your local changes to a remote.

```
git branch new-branch  #creates a new branch
git checkout new-branch #switches to the new branch

# implemented some changes
git add somefile #stages your changes for next commit
git commit -m "implemented some changes" #commits those changes with message

# push* (it's merge) changes to master
git checkout master #switches back to master branch
git merge new-branch #merges your changes from new-branch back into master
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge for more info.