# How to keep up to date Git Branch with master

Tags: git, github

Sometimes we need to work with a team or remotely from home one please to another. So GitHub is the best place for this to avoid problems loosing project and work together. So When we create a project and create branches for others. They need to keep up to date with master branch. So We face problem how to keep up to date other branches with master.

Answer (score 1):

You can do rebase which keeps your branch upto date with master. Rebase will pull all the changes.

```
git rebase origin/master
```

So the workflow will be

1. Checkout to master on your local using

   `git checkout master`
2. Do pull using

   `git pull`
3. Then checkout to your desired branch using

   `git checkout yourbranchname`
4. Then do rebase

   `git rebase origin/master`

If any merge conflict occurs then resolve it !! if not then you are lucky :)

Comment: @Mukta yes it will fetch all the changes from master.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605231/git-merge-branch-into-master .  And if not, you can find the answer here.

Comment: Yeah, I followed that before but I was looking for elaborate answer. Like someone works in the branch didn't git add. Did git merge with master or something did mismatch so it's like unsatisfied answer. But you did really great. I am happy with our answer. Thank  you so much.