# Git pull vs fetch + merge, what is the point of merging without a fetch first?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-fetch

A git pull is a git fetch then a git merge.  But, specifically, why would one ever git merge without doing a fetch first?  i.e. why would it be possible to break one seemingly unitary operation into two sub-operations?

Comment: To merge something they already have locally and don't need to fetch from the remote?

Comment: where would the local something come from?

Comment: For example if you created a branch to work on a specific feature, finished it and wanted to merge that work back into the trunk. You can do that all without touching a remote.

Comment: would you not still have to fetch from your feature branch and merge from it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch    just in case anyone thinks a git pull is not fetch + merge.  I don't understand why the downvotes.  Nobody can answer it's too hard lol.

Comment: Not if the branch is already in your local repository, you wouldn't; fetch is for getting any changes you don't have locally from the remote: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git merge branch into master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605231/git-merge-branch-into-master)

Answer (score 8):

(I see this is rather downvoted already, but as a sort of philosophical question, I think it makes sense.  It *is* a hard question though!)

> A git pull is a git fetch then a git merge.

Technically, it's a `git fetch` followed by a second Git command.  You can choose which second command to run.  The usual two are `git merge` or `git rebase`.  (Sometimes—rarely—`git pull` will end up running `git checkout` as its second command, but that is not one you can choose with an option.  That's just what happens if you run `git pull` in a totally-empty repository.  I have not checked to see what happens on an orphan branch, but that's also a reasonable place for `git pull` to run `git checkout`, since that's the same situation as in a new, totally-empty repository.)

> But why would one ever git merge without doing a fetch first?

Why would you write code?  Why do anything at all?  In one sense, the answer is just *because I want to*.  So why merge at all?  Because you want to.  But that just pushes the question down another level: why do you want to?  Why do you want to run `git merge` at all?

To answer *that* question, we should look at what `git merge` can do.  From a high level overview—as in, what are the outcomes of running `git merge`—there are four possibilities:

- Nothing at all: `git merge` says there is nothing to merge, or the argument(s) we give it are invalid, or are in error, or whatever.  That's probably not why we wanted to run `git merge`, but it's a possibility, so we have to keep it in the list.
- We get what Git calls a *fast-forward merge*, which is not actually a merge at all.  That might be what we want!  Or it might not.  I won't go into any detail here other than to say that a "fast-forward merge" is really more of a *check out the commit we named in the merge command, and drag the branch name forward* operation here.
- We get one or more *merge conflicts*, and the merge stops in the middle.  That's probably not what we want, but it might be a stumbling block on the way to getting what we do want.
- We get a *merge commit*, which is otherwise like any ordinary commit—a new commit that adds to the current branch—except that it has an extra *parent commit*.  This means that when we view the history in the repository—remember, "the history in the repository" consists of the *commits* that are in the repository—we'll have a fork in the view, so that we can continue traveling into the past down the "main line" of this branch, or we can travel down the other leg of the merge, into *that* past.

That last one—getting the final merge commit—is probably why we ran `git merge`.  In fact, if we want to make sure we get a merge commit, even if `git merge` *could* do a fast-forward instead, we should run `git merge --no-ff`.

Sometimes, though, getting that fast-forward is what we want.  In that case, we should use `git merge --ff-only`.  If a fast-forward is not possible, this will produce an error and fail the merge, rather than producing a merge commit.

#### That still doesn't answer the question

As before, this just pushes the question down another level: why do we want, or not want, a *merge commit?*  We did, at least, see what a merge commit *is:* a fork in history.  Remember that while we work *forwards*, making new commits, Git works *backwards*.  So when we combine two histories, the backwards view splits one history into two.

To see why we might want to split history like this, we have to think backwards like Git does.  Remember that each commit holds a *snapshot*, and therefore, to get changes, we must compare that snapshot to some earlier snapshot.  With an ordinary non-merge commit, this is easy:

```
...--P--C--...
```

Here `C` is the child commit of parent commit `P`.  There is only one way to go, from `C` back to `P`.  The *change* in `C` is whatever is *different* between the snapshot in `P` and the snapshot in `C`.  That's what `git show hash-of-C` will show us, or what `git log -p` will show us.

At a merge commit, however, there are two parents:

```
...--P1
       \
        C--...
       /
...--P2
```

To see what happened between `P1` and `C`, we have Git compare these two snapshots.  To see what happened between `P2` and `C`, we have Git compare *these* two snapshots.  So if we want to be able to see both sets of changes, we need both parents recorded.

That's one possible motive for getting *a* merge (a merge commit), which would in turn motivate us to run `git merge`.  Now let's look at another.

#### How Git finds commits

Commits in Git are numbered, but the numbers *look* random.  They're not actually random at all: each number is a cryptographic checksum of the contents of the commit.  That way, each one will be unique.<sup>1</sup>  Git then stores these commits—and other internal Git objects, which are similarly numbered<sup>2</sup>—in a [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database).  So the way Git finds a commit is by its hash ID.  If you memorize each hash ID in your entire repository, you can just supply the hash ID to get the commit back.

The thing is, nobody<sup>3</sup> wants to memorize hash IDs.  Fortunately, there is no need to do so.  Each commit already stores the hash ID of its parent or parents, so all we—and Git—need is the ability to store the hash ID of the *last* commit in some chain of commits.  We do this with a *branch name:*

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- branch
```

The branch name stores the hash ID of the last commit in the chain, which in this case is represented by the letter `H`.  We say that the branch name *points to* the commit.  Meanwhile commit `H` stores the hash ID of its parent `G`, so we say `H` points to `G`.  Similarly, `G` points to `F`, and so on.

This gives us the entire history of the branch, starting from the end and working backwards.  With just one name—a branch name—we get the entire chain of commits.  We need only remember the *name* of the commit we'd like to start with.  And, as we add new commits to a chain, using `git commit`, Git automatically updates the name, so that:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch
```

becomes:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- branch
```

and the fact that there's now a new *last commit* never needs to bother us at all.

That's a motive for *branch names*, and not—yet anyway—a motive for using `git merge`, but let's keep that in mind, and move on.

---

<sup>1</sup>This assumes that each commit's content is unique to that commit.  Fortunately—and/or through careful design—it is.  It also assumes that the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) does not apply.  Unfortunately, it does.  Fortunately, it doesn't ever accidentally happen in practice.  Unfortunately, it can happen [deliberately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452).  Fortunately, this known collision doesn't affect Git.  Meanwhile, Git is moving to a new hash algorithm.

<sup>2</sup>These objects need not be unique: for instance, two commits that, for whatever reason, store the same snapshot, can literally just share the snapshot.  File contents are stored as internal objects as well, and this automatically de-duplicates the files.

<sup>3</sup>Well, nobody I know, anyway.  I don't even want to memorize an important hash ID like that for the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452).

---

#### If merges split history when going backwards, what about forwards?

Suppose we have a chain ending at `H` like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch1
```

and we add a second branch name, `branch2`, that also points to commit `H`.  Then we make two new commits on `branch1`, so that we have:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H   <-- branch2
```

Now we make two new commits on `branch2`, so that we have:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

When viewed *backwards* by starting at the two "last" commits `J` and `L`, these two histories *join* at commit `H`.  If that seems significant or propitious, well, now you're starting to understand Git.

In order to come up with the *snapshot* for a new merge commit, a `git merge` of these two commits, `J` and `L`, will *find* commit `H`.  It does so using these backwards-pointing arrows, by following the history from `J` to `I` to `H`, and from `L` to `K` to `H`.  Now that `git merge` has found the *best common starting point*, it can compare what's in `H`'s snapshot to what is in `J`'s, to see what we did, and to what is in `L`'s, to see what they did.

This action, of comparing the merge base commit to two other commits, is the *to merge* or *merge as a verb* part of a `git merge`.  The fact that Git can do this on its own, and often pretty successfully, is both amazing<sup>4</sup> and useful.  It is this *merge as a verb* action that makes `git merge` truly useful.

---

<sup>4</sup>Git is just applying some simple diff-combining rules, which are purely textual.  Git has no concept of the *semantics* of the text that it is combining.  Once you realize this, it starts to make sense why Git can combine many kinds of source code, but not—for instance—a lot of XML text.

---

#### We're not quite done with true merges

The ability for `git merge` to leave behind a *merge commit* is useful for history purposes, but in some ways this just an adjunct to the merge-as-a-verb action, because it leaves the graph set up such that the *next* `git merge` operation has a reasonable merge base.  To see how that works, consider what you get if you're working on two separate branches, and occasionally merge one into the other.  Let's start with an "after" picture, and then get the "during" pictures that led to this:

```
            o--o--o--o--o--o   <-- feature/short
           /       \
...--A----F----M----N---P   <-- develop
      \       /        /
       o--o--B--o--o--C--o--o   <-- feature/tall
```

Here, we have a branch named `develop` on which we might write an occasional hotfix commit (such as commit `F`), but we don't write *new features* that mess with the actual use of the system.  So here's our first "during" picture:

```
            o--o   <-- feature/short
           /
...--A----F   <-- develop
      \
       o--o--B   <-- feature/tall
```

As we work on the new features, though, we realize that some of what we're doing is just preparation work that really should be in the development line, or is ready, or whatever.  We're at commit `B` on the `feature/tall` branch now, and we decide that this stuff—everything we did on `o-o-B`—should go into `develop` right now.  So we run:

```
git checkout develop
git merge feature/tall
```

If this merge goes well, Git makes new merge commit `M` on its own:

```
            o--o   <-- feature/short
           /
...--A----F----M   <-- develop
      \       /
       o--o--B   <-- feature/tall
```

The *merge base* commit that Git used to *make* `M` was commit `A`; the input commits were `F`—the hotfix we kept—and `B`.  Now that commit `M` is done, we keep working on `feature/tall`:

```
            o--o   <-- feature/short
           /
...--A----F----M   <-- develop
      \       /
       o--o--B--o--o--C   <-- feature/tall
```

Meanwhile, we—or someone, anyway, working on `feature/short`—has found that they should make merge commit `N`, which gives us:

```
            o--o--o   <-- feature/short
           /       \
...--A----F----M----N   <-- develop
      \       /
       o--o--B--o--o--C   <-- feature/tall
```

When we go to merge `feature/tall`—or more precisely, commit `C`—into the tip commit of `develop` (commit `N`), Git will work backwards from `N` to `M`, then to `F` and `B` both.  In other words, commit `B` is *on* the `develop` branch, through the merge commit.  Git will also work backwards from `C`, through the two `o` commits, to `B`, which is therefore the best *shared* commit.  So the next merge-as-a-verb process only has to get our `o-o-C` changes into `develop`, while keeping the `M-N` changes (with `M`'s "changes" being reflected directly through the `B`-vs-`N` comparison: they are basically just keeping the hotfix).

Once we're *done* with a feature, we merge it in one last time, and then, because the final merge `R` has `D` as a parent, we can drop the *name* `feature/tall` entirely.  If we need to find commit `D`, we'll do that by looking at the second parent of commit `R`:

```
            o--o--o--o--o--o   <-- feature/short
           /       \
...--A----F----M----N---P--------R   <-- develop
      \       /        /        /
       o--o--B--o--o--C--o--o--D
```

That this all works so well (or as well as it does) is why we use `git merge`.  The diff-combining plus some basic graph theory get us pretty far.

#### I may have convinced you about merging, but what about `git fetch`?

If we all agree that `git merge` is useful, why wouldn't we always run `git fetch` first?  Well, before we answer that, we need to ask why would *ever* run `git fetch`, much less just before running `git merge`.  To understand that, we need to consider the fact that Git is a *distributed* version control system.

We get a copy of some repository, and work in *our* copy and make new commits.  Someone else may control the original repository—the one we copied—and may be making new commits there.  Or, perhaps that original repository is one hosted on a centralized server type site, such as GitHub or Bitbucket or whatever, and one or more people are sending new commits to it.

**If** we're dealing with this situation, *then* it makes sense to coordinate with other users.  That is, if we're using Git collaboratively *and* we want to get someone else's new commits, `git fetch` is a good way to do that.

As soon as we introduce this extra repository, though, we throw in a lot of complications.  In particular, *commits* get shared: they have universe-wide unique hash IDs, so any two Gits, at any time, can join up with each other temporarily, and just show each other their hash IDs.  If one Git has a hash ID and the other does not, that one Git has a commit or other internal Git object that the other lacks.  The `git fetch` and `git push` commands give us ways to connect a pair of Gits and have them transfer commits to each other.  So *commits*, which always have a unique number, are easy to share this way.  But here's the problem: *branch names* aren't shared this way, at all.

To see *why* branch names aren't shared, just imagine that you and a friend or co-worker are both doing work and plan to collaborate.  Let's give the two people involved here names.  We'll use the [standard names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob), Alice and Bob, and we'll talk about a setup with *three* repositories:

- Alice has Alice's repository;
- Bob has Bob's repository; and
- both of them share with each other using a central-site third repository like GitHub or Bitbucket.

Both Alice and Bob start with `git clone url`.  This gets them a repository with some commits in it.  Now, there's a secret<sup>5</sup> here: when their `git clone` is not quite finished yet, *neither Alice nor Bob have any branches at all*.  Instead, they have what Git calls *remote-tracking branch names*, which I call *remote-tracking names* because they're not actually *branch* names.

If you (or Alice or Bob) run `git clone -b branch url`, what you are doing is directing your Git to run `git checkout branch` as the last step of its clone operation.  It's this final step that actually creates *your* branch name.  If you omit the `-b` option, your Git asks the other Git—the one at *`url`*—what branch name to use.  The usual default right now is `master`.<sup>6</sup>

It's this final step that actually creates your own branch in your repository.  So Alice gets a `master` and Bob gets a `master`, and both of their `master`s are based on their `origin/master` which itself is based on the `master` that's in the third Git, at the central server.

---

<sup>5</sup>It's not really a secret, but it's typically overlooked in introductions to Git.

<sup>6</sup>GitHub plan to change this to `main` soon, for new repositories; existing repositories will still recommend whatever they recommend.  GitHub provide a web interface to let you adjust any repository you control.

---

#### Let's draw the Alice-and-Bob situation

We now have three repositories, which we—as some sort of omniscient deity can somehow know all about all the time—so we'll draw a picture of all three:

```
central-server:  ...--G--H   <-- master

alice: ...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master

bob:   ...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

Now Alice, being faster than Bob, makes a new commit:

```
                 I   <-- master
                /
alice: ...--G--H   <-- origin/master
```

Bob makes his commit second; since commits have unique IDs, we'll call his `J`:

```
bob:   ...--G--H   <-- origin/master
                \
                 J   <-- master
```

Since we have this omniscient overview, let's draw what would happen if we combined all the commits into one repository:

```
                 I
                /
[all]  ...--G--H
                \
                 J
```

What *names* should we use to find commits `I` and `J`?  One name, like `master`, is only allowed to remember *one* commit.  So there's no right name to use here.

For Alice and Bob to co-operate, one of them must send his or her commit back to the central server, using `git push`.  The `git push` command is *not as clever as `git fetch`*.<sup>7</sup>  It works by sending a commit to some server,<sup>8</sup> and then asking the server's Git to set its—the server's Git's—branch name to remember that commit.  So if we assume Alice gets there first again, we have this global view:

```
central-server:  ...--G--H--I   <-- master

alice: ...--G--H--I   <-- master, origin/master

bob:   ...--G--H   <-- origin/master
                \
                 J
```

(I've linearized the drawing a bit to save space: put `I` to the right of `H`).

Bob simply doesn't have commit `I` yet.  He must run `git fetch` to pick up `I` from the server.  After that, he gets:

```
bob:   ...--G--H--I   <-- origin/master
                \
                 J   <-- master
```

That is, *his* Git now knows that `origin/master` should identify commit `I`, and his commit `J` is only on his `master`.

If Bob tries to `git push` his commit `J`, he'll ask the server to set *their* `master` to point to `J`.  They will refuse because if they do that, *they* will lose *their copy* of commit `I`.  This happens regardless of whether Bob knows that commit `I` even exists: the *central server* knows, and *that* is the machine on which a Git that is doing checking, is doing the check.

Since Alice beat Bob to the punch, it's now Bob's job to decide what to do about the fork in history between Alice's commit `I` and Bob's commit `J`.

---

<sup>7</sup>The concept of remote-tracking names didn't exist in early Git, and the extra cleverness was only added into `git fetch`, because it doesn't really make sense in `git push`: server repositories often have no *person* attending them all the time, so there's no one to take advantage of it.

<sup>8</sup>To receive a `git push`, a site has to provide some sort of authentication and access control, because Git doesn't.  Providing authentication and access control is enough to call the system a server.  You can `git fetch` from a client that doesn't have all this stuff in it, and Alice and Bob could do peer-to-peer Git without bothering with a central server at all, if they like, by using `git fetch` to communicate with each other.  But that requires that they put up a read-only service that lets the other grab commits without first authenticating.  Or, if they have a nice enough and secure enough system, they can just offer ssh or web service on their own system directly.  It's kind of a pain though, which is why services like GitHub are so popular.

---

#### Now we can see why Bob wants to `git fetch`

Bob wants to run `git fetch` now because:

- Bob wants to *cooperate* with Alice, not run roughshod over her;
- Bob has seen a `git push` failure, or Bob has preemptively run `git fetch` to avoid seeing a `git push` failure.  Either way, Bob now knows that commit `I` exists.

Bob can now run `git merge`, or `git rebase`, or any other Git command, to arrange to do something about his commit `J` so that it fits better with Alice's commit `I`.

#### But that gives us a motive to fetch-and-merge!

Just so: Bob's situation shows us why Bob would run `git fetch` and then `git merge`, and your question is more along the lines of why Bob might run `git merge` *without* first running `git fetch`.  Why would he do that?

Ultimately, if he did do that, we would have to ask him why.  But here are some possibilities:

- Alice doesn't exist.  There is no central-server repository.  Bob is working on his own.
- Or, whether Alice exists or not, Bob created several branches on his own, making some commits that he has never given to anyone else.  No one else has those commits, so no one else could possibly be using those commits for any purpose.  Bob can safely merge those commits without regard to what others might have done because no one *could* have done *anything*.
- Or, Bob got Alice's commit, and it's *wrong*.  Bob does not want Alice's commit.
- Or, Bob got Alice's commit, and it's right, and Bob has realized that he should have created a `feature/tall` branch.  He can do that now *instead of* merging.

#### That last one is one of my motives for avoiding `git pull`

That last possibility is one reason *I* don't use `git pull`.  I like to run `git fetch` as step 1, then *look at what happened*.

Depending on what `git fetch` fetched, I might decide to run:

1. nothing, because there's nothing to do;
2. `git merge --ff-only`, to make sure that I can do a fast-forward instead of a merge;
3. `git log` (perhaps with `-p`), to look at new stuff;
4. `git rebase`, because the new stuff I looked at in step 3 is good and mine adds on nicely;
5. `git checkout -b` to make a new branch;

or something else I've forgotten to list (other than `git merge`, which I almost never want).  So I do often run `git fetch` first, and then `git merge --ff-only`, but I often stick some other command in between the two operations.

Other people have different motivations.  The point here is that while the fetch-and-merge, or fetch-and-rebase, sequence is very common and perhaps *deserves* to  have a convenience command like `git pull` that does it for you, it's not the only way to work.

Comment: I made myself an alias, `git mff`, that just runs `git merge --ff-only`. If I'm doing active development on something, I tend to run `git fetch` and then `git mff` and if that *fails* I know I should check to see if I should rebase. It's a shortcut—actually looking is better—but depending on how much of a rush I'm in, I find it a useful shortcut sometimes.

Comment: The `git pull` command does allow you to pass the `--ff-only` flag, or even configure it in, but for some reason, I just don't *like* to do that. I'm not 100% sure why, but I can point to one fairly solid reason: sometimes I'm running as some other user (helping someone else out, or logged in to the server, or whatever) and don't have my personal setup. In that case, running `git mff` just fails and I remember that I have to spell it all out.

Comment: Thanks for answering so comprehensively.  I can't believe it was closed with "This question needs to be more focused".  There is no simpler way to state it, and the general reasoning you provided is exactly what was called for.

Comment: Well ... this question and answer is, in a sense, an abuse of StackOverflow, which is supposed to be about *small* answers to a *specific technical question*, rather than about larger philosophical-type answers to "meaning of life" type questions (which for computer software, perhaps belong on the softwareengineering site).

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps if you do a fetch without a merge for some reason and later u just merge because u know there r problems where u fetched it from?

Comment: Why would this not be a valid reason to do a merge without a fetch?  You have already fetched some dev from main, you know there was a problem with the code on main that happened after your fetch, so you merge without doing another fetch.