# Git merge branch with another empty branch

Tags: git

I have a branch X, from that one I made branch Y, and from that one I made branch Z.

I made changes in Z but not in Y. I want to bring all the changes from Z into Y and delete Z.
I know it's a simple merge but I don't want to mess it up!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git merge branch into master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605231/git-merge-branch-into-master)

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are on branch `Z`

```
git checkout Y
git merge Z
git branch -d Z # this will delete branch Z only if there are no new changes on Z, it is a sage delete so to say, force delete is -D (uppercase)
```

if branch `Z` has also been pushed to remote and you also want to delete it there you need to

```
git push origin --delete Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could put Y where Z is and drop Z

```
git branch -f Y Z
git checkout Y
git branch -d Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use git merge command.

Go to branch Y : `git checkout Y`

Merge branch Z into Y : `git merge Z`

Delete branch Z : `git branch -d Z`

Read this for more reference : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge