# How to pull from main branch to development branch?

Tags: git

I want to pull all the changes from the main to my development branch without any error. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git merge branch into master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605231/git-merge-branch-into-master)

Comment: Depends on what the errors are.

Comment: Conflicts are **not** errors.

Answer (score 0):

It calls merge in git.

1. Checkout to your development: `git checkout development`.
2. Merge from Main to development: `git merge main`

that's it.

If you have merge errors. You have to solve this errors in your code.