# Getting lots of merge conflicts in the app/build/intermediate directory of my Android app

Tags: android, git, github, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I was working on my Android app in a development branch. I am at a point where I want to merge my changes into master, I figured I'd use the method suggested in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168677/merge-development-branch-with-master) where I merge master into the dev branch to take care of any potential issues before actually going to master. So I executed the following commands while in my dev branch:

`git add .` - to add all my current changes

`git commit -m"My commit message` - to commit my changes

`git push origin devBranch` - to push my changes up to github

`git merge master` - to merge my master branch into the dev branch

This is when I was hit with the following conflicts which I had never seen before:

```
warning: Cannot merge binary files: app/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ (HEAD vs. master)
Auto-merging app/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_
Auto-merging app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merger.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merger.xml
Auto-merging app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
Auto-merging app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v17/values-v17.xml
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v17/values-v17.xml
Auto-merging app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/compile-file-map.properties
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/compile-file-map.properties
Auto-merging app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugAndroidTestResources/compile-file-map.properties
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugAndroidTestResources/compile-file-map.properties
Auto-merging app/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/layout.json
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/layout.json
Auto-merging app/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable.json
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable.json
Auto-merging app/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-xhdpi-v4.json
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-xhdpi-v4.json
Auto-merging app/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-hdpi-v4.json
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-hdpi-v4.json
Auto-merging app/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values.json
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values.json
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

My issue is that I don't know how to fix these conflicts since they're in intermediate files that I've never touched, I'm assuming this is all generated code. Maybe I'm getting myself into trouble by doing `git add .` but that's the way I've always done it, adding each individual file I change doesn't seem practical (and I would want to add the changed generated file too, wouldn't I?).

Am I getting these conflicts due to the way I'm merging? If I switch over to my master branch and merge the dev branch into master would I have the same issues? I'm afraid to try this, but it was the way I was merging changes previously and never gave me any issues like this.

Comment: This has a bad smell.  Your intermediate build target directory should ideally not even be visible to Git.  The fix is to not have build files inside the `.git` folder.

Comment: Add a `.gitignore` file with a `app/build/` line in it.  You can find a great example here:   https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore.  After adding it you can just `git rm` the build folder.  Build products should almost never be in source control.

Answer (score 2):

Make your `.gitignore` file like this:

```
.idea
out
target
*.iml
log
local.properties
build
android/libs
/.gradle
```

Commit it and then do merge.