# Git commands to merge/rebase dev branch to master

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I currently have a master branch and I branched out from it to code on a new dev branch

How to merge or rebase dev on master locally and then remotely, without losing commits or descriptions ?

Comment: Depending on what's in master, `git checkout master` - `git merge dev` - `git push` should suffice. If `git push` fails, it's because people have made changes to the master branch in the origin. You should look at [Pull Requests](https://yangsu.github.io/pull-request-tutorial/) instead though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge development branch with master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168677/merge-development-branch-with-master)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no other changes on the `master` branch you can use a [fast-forward merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---ff):

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff dev
git push origin master
```

At that point, both `master` and `dev` would be referring to the same commit.

Comment: `git push origin master`, I suppose?