# Is there a way to specify that the merge conflict should be resolved "as ours" when using VSTS web api/interface?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-merge

This post is inspired by https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180316-00/?p=98255, specifically by the part where the patch branch needs to be merged to the feature branch "as ours".

The VSTS web interface does not seem to provide any dials here, all it has to say is:
[image]

But maybe it is still possible? Is there a configuration option that allows it or maybe it is possible through REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with the [Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab), it works for me.

Another workaround is resolving the conflicts with Visual Studio (See R[esolve merge conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio)) or [Resolve Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/resolve-command?view=vsts) locally first, then Pull Request to merge.

Another thread for your reference : [How to resolve merge conflict in pull request in VSTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692989/how-to-resolve-merge-conflict-in-pull-request-in-vsts)