# What do I do after resolving all of my merge conflicts and commiting them?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to merge a pull request with my project, but it had conflicts. I download their branch and then went through each file and solved the conflicts, then I committed each file.

I followed the instructions here: https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line

At the end it says "You can now merge the branches on the command line or push your changes to your remote repository on GitHub and merge your changes in a pull request." but I don't understand what this means.

How do I merge the pull request with my resolved merge conflicts?

if I try to just `git push` i get this:

> ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first) hint: Updates were
>   rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not have
>   locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing hint: to
>   the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint:
>   (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`

Comment: you have two ways to solve. Please reference this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692989/how-to-resolve-merge-conflict-in-pull-request-in-vsts).

Comment: it sounds like I want to "Merge from target to current branch prior to completing the PR" but it doesn't say what commands to use

Comment: You followed the wrong instructions. This is the page you want: https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github A merge conflict during a pull request is special, because github adds extra commits to the branch.

Comment: that page says "Tip: If the Resolve conflicts button is deactivated, your pull request's merge conflict is too complex to resolve on GitHub. You must resolve the merge conflict using another Git client like Atom's Git integration or the command line. For more information see "Resolving a merge conflict using the command line."", which is the page i was originally on. I am trying to merge it via command line

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to push your changes, now including the merge resolution to your main repository

Comment: am I pushing their branch? or will it just push their whole branch and changes to my master?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me whether you used `git fetch` to obtain all of your *and* their commits so that everything was up to date all around, ran `git merge` locally, resolved all conflicts, and committed locally, or not.

If you *did* do all that, the error simply means that *after you started* the merging process, the GitHub repository where you got the most recent commits from, got some *even more recent* commits.  You must now repeat some of the work you just did.  You can keep the merge you made, and its resolutions, or just start over.  If you start over, you'll generally have to re-make all the resolutions you made already, which is often rather painful, and of course, if this takes a while, this situation can easily happen again:  The Git repository you're getting commits from, then merging your PR with, is a moving target, and you have to finish all your work before it moves again.

If you *didn't* do all that, then the problem is simply that you didn't do all that.  Always make sure your own Git repository has *all* the commits that their repository has when you start: update your Git repository with:

```
git fetch origin
```

and use `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` or a graphical Git browser (`gitk` or any fancier one) to see how *your* branch names now stack up against your *remote-tracking* (`origin/*`) names.  Make sure your `master` matches their `master`.  Get the to-be-merged commits from the GitHub repository using `git fetch refs/pull/number/head:to-merge` or similar.  (You may want to create a `pr-number` or `pr/number` branch locally to deal with multiple pull requests "at the same time", more or less.)

Not all of this is really very well described on the GitHub help pages, in my opinion, but setting up the proper background and then describing it properly takes a *lot* of words and examples.