# Azure DevOps Resolve Pull Request Conflict

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

So, I have a very strange issue with Azure.
In pull request, it is detecting some conflicts, but don't show up where they are, and what I need to change.
Prior that, Visual Studio picked up a lot of junk from `.vs` folder, and there was shown conflicts with that.

So, I deleted those files in the branch, and now it is just blank window informing, that there are conflicts.
But I see no place, where I could resolve the conflicts, like in VS when committing, it opens up the diff window, to solve those. Here I see nothing.
I have tried to follow this paper, but it didn't help - [https://dzone.com/articles/git-operations-with-visual-studio-part-2#:~:text=Just%20click%20on%20the%20%22Conflicts,open%20the%20conflict%20resolving%20tool](https://dzone.com/articles/git-operations-with-visual-studio-part-2#:%7E:text=Just%20click%20on%20the%20%22Conflicts,open%20the%20conflict%20resolving%20tool)

My Error - https://prnt.sc/u1qowm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve merge conflict in pull request in VSTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692989/how-to-resolve-merge-conflict-in-pull-request-in-vsts)

Comment: I found a solution. This was to install the extensions for Conflicts. But I can't understand, why this diff window is not included automatically. I would say, that this is a basic necessity in merges.

Comment: Yeah, the extension is one of the answers on the linked question.  Most likely if you had followed the method from Git you would have gotten the conflicts also.  In general, I'd think you should manage the conflict resolution outside the GUI when possible.  Who can say why it isn't included, but in general I don't think Microsoft goes and spends effort on work where a community solution is already available.

Comment: Yeah... That's sad. But thing is, I don't think it is possible to make pull requests in Azure from Visual Studio. It just redirects to Azure DevOps. So using GUI is the only choice here

Comment: All the PR is doing is doing a test merge from your branch to the target branch.  If you do a merge of origin\{target} to your PR branch, you will likely see the same conflicts.  That's basically what the linked question is explaining.  None of that has to happen in visual studio or related to a PR at all.

Comment: @Raitis Would you please convert your solution into an answer? This  would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a suggestion from @Hugh Lin I am writing answer to my problem. So, the thing is, that Azure DevOps does not really have a functionality to handle the conflicts when merging, or commit the changes.

In commits, it is not really a problem, but in pull requests, it is, because VS doesn't have a interface, to resolve those conflicts, and many of you may be left out there with this problem.

Solution to that, is to install the extension to your organization called - [Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab). It adds new tab called - "Conflicts" where they could be solved

Comment: It works, the extension allow us to resolve all conflicts easily.