# Solve merge conflicts in pull request is xcode in Azure Dev ops

Tags: xcode, azure-devops, pull-request

I can see there are. 3 merge conflicts is pull request.
But when i try to do pull in xcode is shows "unexpected error".
Is there any way i can fix it in dev ops browser or in my xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are merge conflicts in pull request Azure DevOps side.

Azure DevOps does not really have a functionality to handle the conflicts when merging, or commiting the changes.

In commits, it is not really a problem, but in pull requests, it is, because xcode doesn't have a interface, to resolve those conflicts.

Solution here is to install the extension to your organization called -  [**Pull request merge conflict extension**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab&ssr=false#overview)

After installed it to your Azure DevOps Server, you could see a Conflicts tab in Pull Request page, then you could resolve conflicts in web site instead of resolve the conflicts in a local clone.

[image]

> ***Note:*** There is an known issue that the new changes to master branch after the Pull Request creation will not be recognized by Pull
> Request. You need to abandon the current PR then create a new one.
>
> For example, there are two PRs in your repo, feature1 to master and
> feature2 to master. After feature1 merged into master, the existing PR
> from feature2 to master will not show the feature1’s changes. You need
> to abandon it and recreate a new PR. And then you could use the
> Conflict extension to resolve merge conflicts.

[image]

For more details you could also refer *jessehouwing* 's
answer in this similar question: [How to resolve merge conflict in pull request in VSTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692989/how-to-resolve-merge-conflict-in-pull-request-in-vsts)