# How to make a merge of two git branches

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Assuming I have two branches one called `stable` and another called `dev`, and I have given commits in the `dev` branch. How do I merge it to the `stable` via command line ? thankful ;D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge development branch with master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168677/merge-development-branch-with-master)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Take a look at [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work to merge dev into stable.

```
git checkout dev
git pull 
git checkout stable
git pull
git merge dev
git push
```

Don't forget to commit & push your changes on dev first

Comment: Why do you `pull` two times? A simple `git merge` should do the trick and is much faster.

Comment: And also: No one said that there is a remote.

Comment: Just helping a typical use case. If there is a remote, then you'll need to pull to make sure the local branches are up to date.

If there is no remote then
git checkout stable
git merge dev

Comment: Yes, but one pull is enough. You don't need to pull two times.