# Sync git changes with vscode not working

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I tried syncing in vscode but git credentials were not set and the sync failed. Then I pressed Sync in a GitHub for desktop tool and all my changes were discarded.
Is there a way to get them back?..I tried signing in to github in my vscode but nothing helped.

Comment: It sounds like you did not bother to commit the changes before syncing. There's a good chance your changes are gone if that's the case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7147749/459750

Comment: I did commited my changes. Then pressed on 'Sync'.

Comment: Does `git reflog` show you your commit?

Comment: Hi it worked... `git reflog` is the answer!!! Thank u so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command in terminal then try "winget install --id Git.Git -e --source winget"