# Is their a way to revert `git checkout`?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I did `git checkout -- .` mistakenly .

changes neither committed nor stashed..
is their a way to retrieve my changes?

tried `git reflog` changes wasn't reflected in it..

if i commit or stash i know to retrieve but what about checkout without doing either?

things i did,

`git status`

after i noticed some useless changes so i tried to do `checkout` changes instead i did `git checkout -- .`

so is it possible to retrieve?

Comment: Before doing anything else, check if you had opened some of the modified files in an editor. Maybe the editor has the old contents still buffered and you can restore them that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accidentally reverted to master, lost uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes)

Answer (score 8):

You cannot undo such operation. The reflog is a great tool, but records only what happens to refs (branch, tag, HEAD, ...), and here you did not modify any ref.

By typing `git checkout -- .`, you discarded any *unstaged* changes, so Git was never aware of these changes.

Your backup system is your only hope here (using Git doesn't mean one shouldn't do backups, too).

Answer (score 6):

In your IDE (if you haven't closed it since) try using undo. For Visual Studios the undo is (ctrl + z).

Comment: omg undo worked in Sublime Text. Bless you ser!

Comment: You just saved my day dude!

Answer (score 4):

If you use Android Studio, it has Local History when you right click the mouse.

[image: Local History]
[image: Local commit]

Comment: its not an android studio feature.. android studio was the built by jetbrains. jetbrains have git integrated on their IDE

Answer (score 1):

Generally i use `Netbeans` `IDE` for programming and it has Rich features for helping developer,

so it has feature named `History` which stores every changes of that file whenever you save the file it saves it as history.

And it also saves all the commits of git, so it stores all the history from the day you have added project to netbeans to till now,

And additionally you can also compare your historical version of file to current version of file, it is very useful feature.

You can see in below image there is two option under opened file

1.**Source**(in it you can see and edit current file here)

2.**History** (in which you can check all the older version of file.)

[image]

You can see i have `Books.php` file under it in `history` tab, there is list of all the older version here from git commit, you can check all of it and also compare it to current file.

So if you have mistakenly done `git checkout` then you can check that file's history and you can undo the changes or get back your lost changes.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the IDE you used to modify the files in the first place, they might have a backup. For instance in `Vim`, `filename.ext` will have a backup named `filename.ext~`.

Answer (score -1):

Simple!
I was also facing same tension for a few minutes. but I found the solution, which is
When I run checkout, git shows me a warning that is

```
Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

  617bd25 my commit message

If you want to keep it by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:

 git branch <new-branch-name> 617bd25

Switched to branch 'master'
```

So i simply run the suggested command

```
git branch branch-name 617bd25 
git checkout branch-name
```

It solve my problem