# What does git checkout still do after git switch got introduced?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-switch

As everyone knows, `git checkout` is a very overloaded command. And I do understand that certain commands got introduced to distribute, e.g. to `git switch`.

Before I used the following commands:

```
$ git checkout <existing-branch>
$ git checkout <hash>
$ git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
```

So I am wondering after `git switch` got introduced, what is the left purpose of `git-checkout`? Is this a deprecated command?

Comment: `git-checkout` can also be used to restore working-tree files. (Edit: seems that you can use `git-restore` for that)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between git switch and git checkout <branch>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265785/whats-the-difference-between-git-switch-and-git-checkout-branch)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, it doesn't. It only says what is beneficial with `git switch`, but not whats left behind

Comment: The `git checkout` command still does everything it did before, of course. :-) Actually, it's been improved: the bad behavior it used to have, destroying work, now comes out as a complaint that the command is ambiguous. (switch and restore don't have this issue.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's retained at least for backward compatibility. Think about millions of scripts that still use `git checkout` — should we hurry to rewrite all of them? Certainly no.

It's not even deprecated, actually. There is nothing about deprecation in [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout). On the other hand the docs for [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) and [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) say "THIS COMMAND IS EXPERIMENTAL. THE BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE."

Comment: This is very useful. Because you pointed this out, I added the info about the commands being experimental in my answer here: [Various ways to create a branch in git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63418267/4561887)