# How can I create a branch in a detached HEAD?

Tags: git

While using git I have two branches. One points to the origin/master. The other one to a different branch. In between there are a series of commits.

One commit after the origin/master there is this commit:

```
97bc89a  edited to build correctly
```

so I do

```
git checkout 97bc89a
```

and I got

```
you are in 'detached HEAD'
```

it also says that I can create a new branch by

```
  git switch -c <new-branch-name>
```

I ve never used that command before. I was going to do `git checkout -b <new-branch-name>`

Is it any different? How?

Comment: For difference between checkout and switch refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/57265785/8280135

Comment: Your title question is a little odd because you have the answer in your question. :) When you are detached, both `git switch -c new-branch` and `git checkout -b new-branch` will create a new branch from your current commit. Yes, they are the same. Also, capitalizing the letter to be `checkout -B` or `switch -C` will overwrite the branch even if it already exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between git switch and git checkout <branch>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265785/whats-the-difference-between-git-switch-and-git-checkout-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it any different? How?

It isn't really different. The problem has been that `checkout` is so dreadfully overloaded. So, in 2019, Git was updated with two new commands, `switch` and `restore`, that do between them, with greater clarity and predictability, much of the work that `checkout` used to do. They are termed "experimental" but I've been using them very happily.