# What is the difference between git checkout -b and git switch -c?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm confused to which one actually **creates a branch based on the current branch?**

We can even add `git branch <branchname>` on top of them, aren't they all the same?

Comment: You can check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265785/whats-the-difference-between-git-switch-and-git-checkout-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265785/whats-the-difference-between-git-switch-and-git-checkout-branch)

Comment: Different spelling, same results, yes. (However, `git branch newname` has different results: it does not switch *to* the new branch as part of the creation process, while `git checkout -b` or `git switch -c` does.)

Answer (score 1):

It's formally the same thing in terms of results, but it is a newly introduced verb which less responsibility as `checkout`.

Read [this article](https://bluecast.tech/blog/git-switch-branch/) for further information.