# How to get back my uncommitted changes after a git rebase?

Tags: git, github, rebase, pull-request, git-pull

I had some uncommitted changes on my local and I wanted to send a pull request. I did a `git pull --rebase` and forgot committing my local changes.

The `git pull --rebase` has removed all my unsaved/uncommitted contents. How do I get them back?

I don't mind reverting the rebase, all I want is my uncommitted changes back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover from git reset --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard)

Comment: Note that `git pull` is *supposed* to announce that you have unsaved work and refuse to run (`Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes` or `Cannot pull with rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes`).

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7147749/6723384). As that answer says, unless the changes were staged or stashed, you cannot recover them. However you could try using Undo in your IDE, it may undo the changes from the `git pull`.

EDIT: If you're really desperate you could look into reverting at the OS level if you have set up something like Windows Recovery or OS X Time Machine.

Comment: I unfortunately did not stage/stash. Nor can I do the OS level revert on my office machine. I think I lost them, thanks for the answer though.