# How to get uncommited files after git pulling?

Tags: git, github

I pushed my newest branch, while I have uncommited files. After that I pulled the branch. After that, my uncommited files are anymore in the changelist. How can I undo the pull to get my uncommited files back?
I use IntelliJ with the git plugin.

EDIT: Solved by GitHub desktop.

Comment: As long as the files pulled in are not named in the same way as the uncommitted(newly added files) they should remain on disk. Check files on disk, not via intelliJ.  If they are there, restart intelliJ. If that didn't help. Use git bash.

Comment: Most of the files are named in the same way. I checked the files on disk, there are no other files. :(

Answer (score 0):

See: [Accidentally reverted to master, lost uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes)

Check local history of IntelliJ for last resort recovery. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html

If this does not help, I am afraid you have lost your files...

Comment: Both suggestions don't help. I can not find any of the uncommited files.