# git checkout from one branch to another deleted all local changes. How can i retrieve them?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I have changes on `devel` branch. I checked out on `master` without commiting the changes. All the local changes got deleted in `devel`. How can I retrieve them?

Comment: Android Studio local history might help you, and see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes

Comment: Sounds disastrous.  Might be the way android-studio handles stuff.  Try checking your stash history with `git stash list`, but deleting on checkout is super invasive, I would look to remove that feature before continuing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accidentally reverted to master, lost uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio local history might help you, and see here [Accidentally reverted to master, lost uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes), it really depends on your case.