# How to restore uncommitted files after branch change and pull?

Tags: git

How do I restore uncommitted files after running `git stash`, `git pull`, and then switching branches? I do not see any stashed changes when running `git stash list` in the new branch.

For context here is my command history:

```
 1976  git checkout HEAD main-backend/account/api/serializers.py
 1977  git reset HEAD main-backend/account/api/serializers.py
 1978  git checkout HEAD main-backend/account/api/serializers.py
 1979  git checkout HEAD main-backend/account/api/
 1980  git checkout HEAD main-backend/account/apii/
 1981  git checkout HEAD main-backend/account/api/git reset --hard --merge a5938af6
 1982  git reset --hard --merge a5938af6
 1983  git reset --hard a5938af6
 1984  git checkout HEAD^ main-backend/account/api/
 1985  cd main-backend/
 1986  ls
 1987  git checkout answer/api/
 1988  git checkout answer/api/views.py
 1989  cd ..
 1990  git checkout main-backend/answer/api/views.py
 1991  git checkout main-backend/answer/api/views
 1992  git checkout main-backend/answer/api/views.cpython-38.pyc
 1993  git checkout -f HEAD
 1994  git pull
 1995  clear
 1996  ls
 1997  git stash pop
 1998  git stash list
 1999  git branch
 2000  history | tail -25
```

Comment: What are we supposed to see in the screenshot?

Comment: That's the folder path where the files were deleted.

Comment: If they were not committed, and you don't have a backup, I don't think there is a way to recover.

Comment: I don't think `git pull` deletes uncommitted files normally.

Comment: I did also git checkout to a <specific branch> @mkrieger1

Comment: Okay, and then?

Comment: In order to switch branches did you `git stash`? And if so can you `git stash pop`?

Comment: Yes! I did `git stash` @PCDSandwichMan

Comment: Ok then if you `git stash pop` do you see your files?

Comment: It is showing `No stash entries found.` when i write the command `git stash pop`

Comment: What do you get when you run `git stash list`?

Comment: I see nothing. @PCDSandwichMan

Comment: Can you safely share the output of `history | tail -25`? And post the output in your question for the sake of readability.

Comment: Okay, I have edited in my question.

Comment: Oof you git reset. Is that around the time that you lost your changes?

Comment: If so [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes) might be applicable.

Comment: I see no `git stash` only a `git stash pop` and then a `git stash list`. `git stash pop` applies *and removes* the last stash, which would explain why `git stash list` is empty. Where is the `git stash`?

Comment: Where the changes uncommitted or *untracked*? That is, where they new files which were never added?

Comment: `1983  git reset --hard a5938af6` is the culprit: you told Git to throw away uncommitted work, and it did.