# Git / Linux - i've reverted changes which were not staged or commited. Can i do something?

Tags: linux, git

I just reverted some changes in files. These changes were not staged or commited.

Is there anything I can do?

thanks!

Comment: No, not from the Git side. If you're using an IDE of some kind, then check if it has a local history feature, that sometimes helps. Otherwise: learn the lesson, commit more often and re-type what you have produced.

Comment: When in doubt, commit (or at the very least, stash). Easy to get rid of an unwanted commit. Then retrieve it later or not. But unstaged changes just don't exist to git.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accidentally reverted to master, lost uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much you can do to recover your changes.
If you are using Intelli as your IDE there is a "local history" you can access be right clicking on a file in the project view.

Comment: It seems i have a local history in VS Code, thanks man. I might fix it this way

Comment: Just to let you know -- i've fixed the issue thanks to your help. VS Code has local history. Thanks!