# I did commit in vscode to git and all my project has been delete

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

i am totally pannic
i wrote a hole module in node.js, did a commit, the vscode show kind of a git error, i confirmed
and suddenly (we say in hebrew) -'darkness' - all my project disappeared, deleted
it is not it git yet and it is my first commit for this project.
i cant find it on ricycle bin and Timline says 'the active editor cannot provide timeline
information'  - what does it means ???????  and where is my code?

please help me, i have nothing in my life excepet writing code , i cant beleive it happned
what does it means 'the active editor cannot provide timeline
information' ? what is it ??

thanks

i tried open recycle bin and timeline but recieved a message :
the active editor cannot provide timline information

1)timeline is enabled! it is checked
2) i have version from vscode 2022 and updaed right now to vscode 2023 but still cannot see timeline as supposed to show

timeline not requested any extention - so why dont i see my project there ?

Comment: What do you see if you do `git reflog` in the terminal?

Comment: What about using VS Code's local history feature? `Local History: Find Entry to Restore` in the command palette?

Comment: let it be a lesson, before you do some unknown stuff take a backup/zip of your work

Comment: Can you provide the 'kind of a git error' text?

Comment: hi --- git reflog  -->8972406 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD
8972406 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{1}: clone: from https://github.com/binodnepali/nextjs-with-material-ui-example-template.git

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes

Comment: Another place where code can get hidden is the stash: `git stash list`. Can you describe the actions you took when you tried to commit ?

Comment: @rioV8 , the lesson here should be to use a proper Git workflow, with branches and commits right from the beginning, not waiting for the feature to be ready before starting to work with Git.
When using Git properly, there should be no need in using other means of backup/zip, just branches and commits (and maybe pushes to some private remote repository).

Comment: @Mayaa The point is if git is not second nature it is not a bad idea to have a second save guard. I still sometimes make a zip of the project before doing some stuff like a complex interactive rebase

Comment: @rioV8 , before an interactive rebase I create a backup branch. Then I'm free to experiment with my current branch, and in case anything goes wrong I just reset my current branch to point to the same commit as the backup branch. 

I don't need to manage any archives. Git does a terrific job on its own.