# Is there any method for recover deleted file with git?

Tags: git, git-status

I create a repository in the main directory of my mac for mistake. Then with gitgraph extension on vs code i see +10k file added and ready to commit, i press remove modify and now all of my files are deleted. Is there any chache to rehave them?

[git status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTBWJ.png)

Comment: If you haven't ever included a file in a commit, git can probably not restore it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accidentally reverted to master, lost uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes)

Comment: tl;dr: no you can't, especially in this situation. You should restore your latest backup (and hope it's recent ... and exists).

Answer (score 1):

You say "ready to commit". I interpret this to mean that you have stage all files. In this case, the files should all be in the object database. You can access them using

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

([manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck#Documentation/git-fsck.txt---lost-found)). You only get the contents back, but not the file names. These you have to recover in some other way, for example by inspecting the contents.

Comment: At any rate, make a backup of the directory including the .git directory before you mess around any further.