# Git add followed by git reset deleted all my files

Tags: git, gitlab

Hmm, I screwed up...

I have a repo and did a git add . for the first time.

But then realised there are a lot of files that should not be there, so I wanted to reset and then fix the .gitignore  en then redo.

after doing git reset --hard

all my files are gone.

Question, is there a way to "undo" this?

Desperate for help.
I have no other backup, pushing to git was supposed to be my backup ;>)

Comment: Using `git reflog` you can recover the commit(s) which had been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link provided the method to recover the files.

[git add + git reset hard deleted working copy file - undo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197545/git-add-git-reset-hard-deleted-working-copy-file-undo)

It was a bit of a pain, but better than redoing all the work.

I used this command to list all the blobs into a text file (blobs.txt).

```
git fsck | awk '{if(/blob/) print $3}' > blobs.txt^C
```

Then I wrote a short bash script to loop through the file and cat the contents of each blob to a file. Here is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read p; do
        git cat-file blob $p > $p.txt
done <blobs.txt
```

That gave me a load of files named blobxxx.txt
Then I had to manually go through each and determine the filename I needed. Bit of a process, but it worked since I only needed to find my source files.

BIG SIGH OF RELIEVE.

Answer (score -2):

Basically, the answer is no. As you said you screwed up. For more detailed answer please follow this post:
[Recover from git reset --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard)