# How can I recover from "invalid sha1 pointer in resolve-undo" with git fsck?

Tags: git, git-index, git-fsck

I run `git gc` in a repository and get a fatal error:

```
Enumerating objects: 2382, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2382/2382), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (747/747), done.
fatal: unable to read <object-id>
fatal: failed to run repack
```

Running `git fsck --full --no-dangling` provides more detail about the problem with that object:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (2381/2381), done.
error: <object-id>: invalid sha1 pointer in resolve-undo
Verifying commits in commit graph: 100% (287/287), done.
```

I believe this is [caused by a bug that has been fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73271114/733345):

> The resolve-undo information in the index was not protected against GC, which has been corrected with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022).

If my repository is already in this state, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure you don't have any staged changes and [recreate the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115956/733345).

```
rm .git/index
git reset
```

This will recreate the index from `HEAD` without including the `resolve-undo` extension.