# How to reset to the top of a branch

Tags: git

Suppose I'm working on master and I've commit 5 changesets:

```
v1 -- v2 -- v3 -- v4 -- v5
```

now I do 'git reset --hard v3' to go back to a particular point. At this stage, 'git log' will only show the 1st 3 commits and the hash for v4 and v5 will not be displayed. How can I get back to v5 easily?

(I did find a way to do this by poking into the .git directory but it's tedious and I'd like to avoid dealing with .git directory directly).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo git reset --hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374069/undo-git-reset-hard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`git reflog`](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) should contain an entry about the former `HEAD`. You can easily `git checkout` that state (`HEAD@{N}`) and work with it.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the `git reflog` command. `git reflog` shows you the old positions of HEAD with the corresponding SHA-1 keys and the operation done.

You should be able to easily find the SHA-1 key you are looking for. And the you can just use `git branch -f <SHA-1 Key>` or `git reset --hard <SHA-1 Key>` etc..

[Here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) is there documentation, if you want to know more.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: And as TimWolla states, you can also use `HEAD@{N}` to navigate through the old `HEAD` references.