# Git revert reset --hard command

Tags: git

I just made a git reset--hard command by accident. 
Can this git action somehow be reverted? 
I want to obtain back the uncommitted changes. I am using git from the command line.

Can I obtain the code from a still running tomcat/grails instance?

Comment: No. you cannot get back the files that you reverted. Did you push to your github branch ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undoing a git reset --hard HEAD~1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1)

Comment: Can I obtain the code from a still running tomcat/grails instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the changes were not committed or staged, the answer is no.

If you committed changes, you can find back since the commit objects are there.

If you staged your changes (using `git add`), you can still find back your changes, because the `blob` objects for your changes have been generated.

**First of all, please copy your whole git repository as a backup.**

Just for investigation, you can `ls -l -t .git/objects` to find these objects by their creating time. Each object is stored with the first 2 characters of the object id as folder name, and the left part as file name. For example, `78/981922613b2afb6025042ff6bd878ac1994e85'. And you can use`git cat-file` to get it's content.

```
git cat-file -p 78981922613b2afb6025042ff6bd878ac1994e85
```

Or just with the short name (first several characters of the id).

```
git cat-file -p 789819
```

To do recovery, I just found an answer for you. Please refer to [Undo git reset --hard with uncommitted files in the staging area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374069/undo-git-reset-hard).

Comment: I did a git add where can I find the blob?

Comment: Generally, it's in `.git/objects`, you may find it by the creating date. Just wait for a few minutes, I try and let you know.

Comment: This is all binary data, how can I view it

Comment: Just update the answer. They are actually the content of your file with some header information that is zip compacted. And these objects are called unreachable or dangling objects. You can also use  `git fsck` to find them.

Comment: I always get a response  "Not a valid object name"

Comment: Are you sure the id is correct? It should combine the folder and file name. Or you can use `git fsck --cache --unreachable` to get the unreachable and dangling blob. Then use `git cat-file` to have  try.

Comment: Sorry. I missed two folder charachters at the start. You rock! Saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

If the changes were never committed, the answer is no, you can't.

If you did a hard reset and lost committed changes, you can get them back by inspecting the [reflog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get back uncommitted changes until you had not make a temporary patch before "git reset --hard" 
now you can "git pull" to synchronous.

But there is some tricky way you can get your uncommitted changes only if you have did some following commands before "Git reset --hard" :
1. git diff
and to exit from that if you had press ctrl+z

then you can get that back by command "fg". because ctrl+z will make the git diff command running at background. if you had not done above before  "Git reset --hard", sorry you have to write changes again. better luck.