# How do I undo a `git reset --hard HEAD~1`?

Tags: git

I just made a huge accident. I wanted to undo a local commit and I ran `git reset --hard HEAD~1`. However I had many uncommited files (about two days of work).

All the uncommited changes have been reset too.

Help!

How do I undo a `git reset --hard HEAD~1`?

Comment: It's possible to get back the commit you resetted but I don't think there's an option getting back your uncommited changes. Sorry :/

Comment: NOooooooooOOoOoOOoooooooooooooooooo

Comment: You can have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374069/undo-git-reset-hard-with-uncommitted-files-in-the-staging-area

Comment: "Commit early and often" learned the hard way

Comment: [Commit Often, Perfect Later, Publish Once](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/)

Comment: NOOoonnonononononononoooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can revert ant code you have in your local git folder, whether its was committed or not.

**What can be recovered:**

- All commited changes
- All added items (git add without git commit)
- All loose blobs (dangling files)

**What can't be recovered:**

- Deleted files from the local file system. (You can recover those by using 3rd party tool which scan your drive and recover them)

**How to recover:**
First run **`git reflog`** ro **`git log -g`** to verify what did you clean. Then checkout the commit that you wish to recover.
Now you have to recover added but uncommited files. To find those files run **`git fsck`** and it will print out the dangling files. use **`git cat-file -p <SHA1>`** to print them out to screen and then recover them.

`git log -g` will display the reflog entry for each of your commit.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Claim down!
You can run "git reflog" to find your commit logs, and then run "git reset --hard ".
Hope it works.

Comment: I'm holding off on running anything. The question is whether I can get back the uncommited changes. Reading this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374069/undo-git-reset-hard-with-uncommitted-files-in-the-staging-area

Comment: Sorry. I don't know how you lost your uncommited changes. Do they stay in your working directory?

Comment: @bodacydo no need to hold, make a full copy instead (including `.git` directory) and try something in copy, not in original. But no, unstaged changes are very unlikely to be recovered. Think twice before adding `--hard`, name suggests it is dangerous.