# Is there a way to undo git reset if files are not added?

Tags: git

I stupidly ran `git reset --hard` on my branch. I was in the wrong branch. Unfortunately, I didn't perform `git add .`. Is there a way to get back my work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I do not believe there is a method to get your local code back if it was never added to the local or git repository at any point. If it was added at any point, you could use  **git fsck** to get back the last deleted data that was added at some point. There was another stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374069/undo-git-reset-hard-with-uncommitted-files-in-the-staging-area) talking about that possibility