# git rm undo for the files that are not added

Tags: git

I am newbie to git and I committed a big mistake. Other related thread didn't solve my problem. Here is what happened, it feels like "git rm" worked like linux rm command.

In the beginning I added development folder into git repo using

```
git add dir_name1
```

During last couple of days I created few more files in that directory and renamed a few, I think it requires manually adding new files in git, as I was committing all kind of changes after that but new files didnt save in repo.

Today after finishing the work, I decided to add those new files using

```
git add dir_name1
```

I guess with that new files will be found and added automatically, but when I saw that some temporary files (file ending with "~" in ubuntu) were also added.

In order to remove those tmp files I thought that "git rm" is the counterpart of "git add" so I could do "git rm  dir_name1" followed by delete all files ending with ~ manually, and do "git add dir_name1" again then it will be ok.

so what i did was

```
git rm -r -f  dir_name1
```

My God, the entire directory is missing,restoring with "git reset" and few other tricks didnt restore those new files.

Does "git rm" removes just like linux "rm" command? is there a way to recover those files.

SOSSSSS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108853/recovering-added-file-after-doing-git-reset-hard-head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I saw that some temporary files (file ending with "~" in ubuntu) were also added

A simple `*~` in a `.gitignore` would have prevented that

> I could do "git rm dir_name1" followed by delete all files ending with ~ manually

`git rm -r -f  dir_name1` (or `rm -r -f  dir_name1`) will remove the folder and its content from the disk, with or without `git`.

You might still have a trace of those previously added (staged) files with:

```
git fsck --cache --unreachable $(git for-each-ref --format="%(objectname)")
```

Read more in "[Undo `git reset --hard` with uncommitted files in the staging area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7376959/6309)"

Comment: thank you for the commnad, it returns all "unreachable blob 1685d57d4b460b43de338634b6d5932a0cecf5ad" lines

Comment: @AbhishekK yes, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7376959/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/15472831/6309 will show you what to do with it.

Comment: with your input I was able to recover 90% of work, funny that i used a system in a radically opposite way that is rather intended for safeguarding code :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to go about doing this would be to add the entire directory, and then remove the pesky Linux system files afterwards:

```
git add dir_name1
git rm -r '*.~'
```

If you want to make the `.~` files ignored by Git, then you can do this:

```
echo '*.~' >> .gitignore
```

Alas, if you never committed the `dir_name1` directory, it might be lost in space.