# Is there any way to undo a "`git reset .`"? It 'reverted' all files - all edits have been lost from my working directory

Tags: git, undo, git-reset, git-add, git-stage

I staged a grand number of files for commit.

Then I realized it was better to commit only two of the files,
and then commit the remaining ones in a separate commit.

`git reset <filename>` unstages filename

I wanted to unstage everything,
then restage two files, and commit.
Then stage all remainging files and commit again.

As: "`git add .`"            (adds all files to staging area)
and      "`git reset <filename>`" (removes filename from staging area)
"`git reset .`"  (seemed to make sense to unstage all files)

oops..!
That reverted my working directory to the last committed version,
 - I lost ALL File Edits that I had made! :-(

Anyway to "undo" "`git reset .`" ??

I've not found any documentation on this.
In fact I do not find any documentation on "`git reset .`" at all.
My best guess is that git took the "`.`" to be the value for an option,  other than the filename option.

But is this undoable ?

Comment: For documentation on git reset type `git reset --help` - it might be worth reading the bit about `git reset --soft`

Comment: `git reset .` does not revert or change working directory in any way. It will only undo staging of files. However, if you did `git reset --hard .`, that's another story...

Comment: `git reset` without `--hard` should be non-destructive.

Comment: Actually, this is what SURPRISED me !  `git reset .` interprets the "." not to be a filename parameter, and hence operate as if I had typed `git reset filename1 filename2` etc.  It actually interpreted the "." as a different optional parameter on the 'reset' command.  It operated as though I had typed `git reset --hard`  Try it. You might be shocked! - as I was! Fortunately, once I conjectured that that was likely the case, I was able to find and apply a technique for restoration as though I had Literally typed `git reset --hard`, since `git reset .` acted as if I had typed `git reset --hard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes!**, It turns out, You Can !!

Here is why:  **git interprets `git reset .` as `git reset --hard`**

So that deleted all changes in my working directory, 
reverting everything to the state of my last commit.

There is no *built in* way to recover the file edits I had lost.
However, `git add .` saved a copy of each file that had those edits in them.
We, just need to get a handle on where/how `git` saved the state of said files.

**In short, do perform the following steps:**

**(1):**
`git fsck --cache --unreachable $(git for-each-ref --format="%(objectname)") \
  $(egrep commit all | cut -d ' ' -f 3) > stagedNotCommitted`

This will find and put a list of files that git has indexed (because they had been staged),
but that have never been committed, into a file named
**`stagedNotCommitted`**

Since git does not know the file names for these files, `stagedNotCommitted` will be a listing of the indexed files' hashes.
looking something like

```
 `369c722e8df1c83b6ebfc0dc2d426aa612535203
  63282280da679aa19d6a2a71e08bed8487f7e688
  6a540aa36ee558611528176dbf87ad8e39475222
  9c8ce87dd8aff2abc78d8a5dbe976473c6fea3de
  9e20a6530229dac42cb87dc0a7153edb4bad96b5
  abec86bc81f8b473e5ea8f0320589619d5e726b2
  b830a382cd30308782a1df12e553227100b47ba4
  c8bc4788fee301c8c88ed29739927689742c55bf
  f87c9f32da264e5e0b9de3d1818e291a687adab9`
  ...
```

**(2)**:
From here you can open each file in your text editor (I used Sublime),
and save the ones you wish to recover under the correct name.

The way I went about this was by saving each "unreachable blog" into a temp file as such:
(you can use just the first few digits for each file)

`$ git show 89f45 > _02_89f45
$ git show 07f9c > _03_07f9c
$ git show 23ad5 > _04_23ad5`

...

From there opening all these files in sublime was easy.

Just **re-save** with the appropriate name.

**Done !! :-)**

Note, this only works because I had already **Staged** All the Files I wanted to recover.
Had I not Staged (all) them, I'd outta luck. (or could only recover some of them.)

For more information please visit the following links I found useful on StackOverflow:

This one is Particularly Useful, with a great explanation!
[Undo git reset --hard with uncommitted files in the staging area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374069/undo-git-reset-hard-with-uncommitted-files-in-the-staging-area)

Others:
Good, well explained info:
[How can I undo git reset --hard HEAD~1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1)

This one also has a post linking a plugin that claims to do it for you:
[Recovering added file after doing git reset --hard HEAD^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108853/recovering-added-file-after-doing-git-reset-hard-head/1109433)

Finally, here is an interesting table:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/resetting-checking-out-and-reverting/summary

`Command        Scope           Common use cases
git reset       Commit-level    Discard commits in a private branch or throw away uncommited changes
git  reset      File-level      Unstage a file
git checkout    Commit-level    Switch between branches or inspect old snapshots
git checkout    File-level      Discard changes in the working directory
git revert      Commit-level    Undo commits in a public branch
git revert      File-level      (N/A)`

Answer (score 2):

You never committed those modifications, so no, it's not possible...

Rest assure that I know what your pain feels like... and the good news is that you'll never make this error again!

Comment: Actually, there **IS** a way to do so.  See Accepted Answer for details.