# Git: Undoing uncommitted changes to reset specific file

Tags: git

I have a file in my repository which I accidentally resetted as `git reset --hard`. The file is still in the repository, but as the change wasn't committed I cannot get to it.

I found some related questions:

- [Recovering added file after doing git reset --hard HEAD^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108853/recovering-added-file-after-doing-git-reset-hard-head/1109433#1109433)
- [Accidentally reverted to master, lost uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes)

However with these I just found only some old lost stuff, but not this recent one. Is there a way to kind of `grep` the history just for this specific file?

EDIT: What could help is that I know content of the lost file. Maybe if I could `grep` the dangling blobs/commits with this content?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If so, check for local history, or try undo.

Comment: Unfortunately no, this was on remote host.

Comment: Did you `git .add` before the reset? If not, I do not think there is a way to recover

Comment: The file was tracked in git (it was added), but it just was not commited.

Answer (score 0):

Git does store objects in its database. You MAY be able to find the file by doing this:

```
find .git/objects/ -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort
```

You should get a list of objects by date. Each entry will end with a sha. Take each sha (i.e. d670460b4b4aece5915caf5c68d12f560a9fe3e4), and enter:

```
git show <the sha>
```

You may have to try several before you find the correct file.

My answer is derived from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7376959/4374801

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
git fsck --full --cache --dangling
```

and look for `dangling blob` entries - one of them should be your lost file.

You can try to grep (here we select a bigger set of unreferenced object, just to be sure):

```
git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs --full 2>/dev/null | awk '$2 == "blob" {print $3}' | xargs git grep -a your-search-string
```

It will print SHA-1 of the found blob along with the matched line.

Once you have the hash, use `git show <hash>` to see the file.