# Git rename 35000 items from lost-found directory

Tags: git

I am trying to recover my lost change from a newly created local git repository.

I have no commits in master branch and I did a git reset --hard.

Lost all my staged changes. The files were new and untracked.

Using git fsck --lost-found command I am able to see the files that I lost.

There are 35000 files and I want to get them back with their name and folders structure they were in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo git reset --hard with uncommitted files in the staging area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374069/undo-git-reset-hard-with-uncommitted-files-in-the-staging-area)

Comment: The names are *gone*. There is no in-Git way to reconstruct them. If there's internal data within the content that you can use to construct the names, write a program to use it. Otherwise it's a manual process over all 35,000 files.

Answer (score 0):

`git fsck --lost-found` did create found objects into `.git/lost-found/*/` directory where you may find all of your files contents *(but not the directory structure)*.

Comment: It did so. too many files to manually find and rename. Looking for the solution to reatain those files by a script or some OOTB git feature. Thanks