# How to recover modified files with git checkout?

Tags: git, git-reset

I wanted to check if my new changes to code were compatible with existing database, thus I tried to create a new branch from `HEAD` of remote `ORIGIN`.

I ran exactly the following code :

```
git checkout -b test origin/master
```

Till this time, my modified code was present in new branch. I know this because I saw similar output

```
M filename1
M filename2
M filename3
M filename4
```

I wanted to roll back changes, to the previously pushed commit, hence ran this command

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Running this command, reversed all the changes. I thought that happened only for this branch, but I was wrong. I did some changes to code in this branch (I edited only one file which was earlier modified in master branch)

I think this was where all went wrong, I checked out master branch using

```
git checkout master
```

I see output similar to following

```
M filename1
M filename2
```

This is where I realise all changes were lost. I have tried resetting the HEAD again but no progress.

Is there any way to recover those files, or I have to write all code again?

Comment: Hi, if you do not commit this changes so I doubt there is possibility to recover your changes. If your changes was commited somehow, then after reset hard, there is sstill some sym-links in objects. Try read about git fsck --lost-found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo git reset --hard with uncommitted files in the staging area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374069/undo-git-reset-hard-with-uncommitted-files-in-the-staging-area)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-reset%5D+undo+reset+hard

Comment: `git reset` modifies the branch.  `git reset --hard` also modifies the working directory.  I suspect you misunderstand what a branch is.  It is literally nothing more than an alternate name for a single commit.  We tend to overload it with meaning and also include all of its ancestors back to some merge-base or the root.  It is somewhat dynamic, in that the commit it references changes when you make a new commit, but it is really just a reference to a single commit (and some associated metadata).

Comment: Thanks  for information @WilliamPursell