# Rollback to uncommited changes after hard reset a Git Repository

Tags: git, github, git-svn, git-branch

Mistakenly, i hard reset my git repository. By doing this all the changes that i have made has been gone. Now, i want to rollback Git to all the uncommitted changes. Please help me with this.

Comment: Uncommited changes have never been in Git, you can't "rollback" to them, so your problem really is how to recover deleted files. See http://superuser.com/questions/671773/how-to-recover-deleted-files-on-windows

Comment: @sashoalm I am using amazon ec2, do you know how can i recover that files...

Comment: Were your changes staged but uncommitted, or were they unstaged, as well?

Answer (score 1):

"uncommitted changes" means *local* repo (even though you have a remote repo on amazon ec2)

That means you must have added (`git add`) files to a local clone, then do a `git reset --hard`.

If that is the case, you can still find those added files with a [`git fsck`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck), as described in [Recover files that were added to the index but then removed by a `git reset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10783950/6309):

- first, do a full backup of your current repo
- then try a `git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog`

Comment: @janos please see the screenshot, when i used the above command. http://i.imgur.com/oz5ItHX.png

Comment: @RaviKumar your picture looks fine. As mentioned in the answer I linked (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10783950/6309), you need to do a `git cat-file -p <object hash>` with various SHA1 listed in your picture, in order to see if your recognize the *content* of the files you have lost after the `git reset`.