# ignored files take up space in git repository

Tags: git, file, space

I have a few videos in a directory that is on .gitignore. The files never showed up in any changelog, yet they somehow ended up in the .git/objects directory. It takes up ~150MB instead of 5-10. How is this possible?

I did "*git ls-files*" and "*git diff HEAD FIRST-COMMIT --name-only*" and the files are nowhere to be found.

Comment: Could you do a `git log -1 -- yourIgnoredFile`, to see in which commit it was deleted? (in the off chance it was force added in the first place), as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/16635324/6309.

Comment: The comment doesn't print anything. I did "*git ls-tree --name-only -r @*" for every commit and the files were never committed in the first place.

Comment: If you clone your current repo again, would you still find those objects in the `.git/objects` directory?

Comment: No, they disappear! Thanks, that'll solve the problem, but I'm still curious how it happened. Do you want to put this up as answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Done, but check out musiKk's answer first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround (without actually explaining the root cause) would be to clone one's local repo again.

The OP confirms those `.git/objects` extra files are no longer present in the second clone.

You can try, in the original repo, to [check for objects added but never committed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22471992/6309):

```
git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog
```