# Github Commit and Sync Deleted All Files - All work lost

Tags: github, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime text and a Github plugin.

When I tried to Commit and Sync it reverted all my files to the version in the online (from three days ago).

The commit is not showing up in the history.

Is there any way that I can get my files back?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you might not have added your modification to the index before making:

- your "commit" (which committed nothing as a result) and
- your sync (which might have reset your index to the latest fetched commit)

It is always preferable, in case of trouble, to fallback to the command line and check:

- `git status` to see where you currently are after the sync,
- `git reflog`, to see if there is any old commit with a timestamp that could indicate one that you did,
- `git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog`, to see [if you had added anything to the index that might be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22471992/6309).

Comment: I was about to give up when I tried your git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog. Got back 4hrs of work. You just made my day. Thank you soooo much :)