# Bring back local changes after a checkout

Tags: git

Is there any way to *redo* changes in the working directory after checking them out? I just ssh'd into a server I hadn't been on in a while and saw that there were unstaged changes in the index.  I assumed that this was just scratch work I had done last time, but figured because I didn't commit them they weren't important and ran:

```
$ git checkout .
```

to give myself a clean slate.  Unfortunately this was a bit hasty, because it turns out that last time I was on this server I just forgot to commit, and the majority of the work I had done was in those changes.

I feel like this is a long shot, but is there any way to bring back these local changes to the working directory?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: If Git was made aware of those changes through any means (stashing unstaged, added to staging), then there's a *chance*.  Otherwise, you may be out of luck.

Comment: For future reference, it is often safest to use `git stash` to restore a "clean slate". You can also use `git diff` to see the changes before running `git checkout` or `git reset`.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I figured not.  I'll know to watch out for  this in the future!

Comment: You can't have "unstaged changes in the index".  By definition, anything in the index is staged.  Staged changes you can recover.  Unstaged changes are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either those changes were:

- staged (meaning added to the index), in which case a `git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog` can help.
  See for instance:

  - "[Recover files that were added to the index but then removed by a `git reset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10783950/6309)"
  - "[Recovering added file after doing `git reset --hard HEAD^`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109433/6309)"
- not staged (local private modification in the working tree): in which case, those modifications are lost.