# Recover deleted files from git version controlled dir

Tags: git

It just happened that while trying to remove the byte-compiled files from my .emacs.d directory. I ended up deleting up all the source files i.e .el files. It was a find remove, i.e I ran `find . -name "*.el" -exec rm {} \;`. The .emacs.d directory was under git version control. But from a long time there was no commits. I have tried few suggestions from stackoverflow.com but that too didn't help.  What I tried is as below

```
git checkout -- .
git reset --hard
```

both the commands didn't work and I still do not see my files.

any suggestions would be more than welcome. Please assist.

Comment: What happen if you try to clone the repo again (in a new local directory)? Would you see the `el` files then?

Comment: So they might not have been versioned (or at least not committed). Were there some .gitignore files excluding *.el files? Or were they (the el files) simply added to the index (git add) but not committed?

Comment: git ls-files -d | xargs git checkout --

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/14988152/6309 `git fsck --lost-found | grep blob | awk '{print $3}'`

Comment: "But from a long time there was no commits."
Does that mean that you changed but didn't commit changes for a long time or you did't change at all?

Answer (score 0):

If `git reset --hard` leaves you with a clean working tree, probably such tree was saved in one of the latest commits.

First to do: what's in the repo history?

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
```

Second: if there was a `git reset --hard` with data loss, try running `git reflog`.