# Undo Sync(Github desktop Client) to restore uncommitted changes

Tags: xcode, macos, github

Before commit the changes by mistake, I have clicked on GitHub Desktop Sync button and now all my last 2 week changes has been discarded. Now my local code has come to the same state as was in previous commit.

Is there any way to revert back my lost changes ?

Comment: Is the lost code anywhere in a commit? If so, you can get it back. It it's not in any commit, either locally or on github, and also not in your local uncomitted changes, then it's lost .. forever.

Comment: Did you add your code to the index (stage), before clicking sync?

Comment: @GolezTrol - No...Lost code was not committed. I tried to commit and I got an error with one file was not getting commit. so i just delete that file from file system and by mistake I clicked on Sync.

Comment: @VonC -  GitHib desktop client doesn't ask for separate stage and commit.  Normally I made changes into my code and commit and take a pull and if there is no conflict. I simple push my changes to master.

Comment: Just to be sure, could you check in command line if a `git fsck --lost-found` would help (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14988152/6309)