# Recover files which are added but not commited

Tags: git

I am using git version control system in my project. Today after completing my work, I have added all the files using

`git add [file-name]`

and then forget to commit changes to server, I have pulled and pushed commands as below

```
git pull --rebase origin [branch-name]
git push origin [branch-name]
```

After a minute I got that I have forgot to commit (using command `git commit -m "comment"`)  changes to server. Now, is there any way to get my changes back? I've already googling and tried find similar issues on Stack Overflow but could not get satisfied solution.

Comment: May this link will help you. https://www.quora.com/Git-revision-control/How-do-I-retrieve-added-files-but-not-committed-from-a-reset

Comment: Isn't your changes on the staging area?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been already answered on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782978/recover-files-that-were-added-to-the-index-but-then-removed-by-a-git-reset)

For what I understand of what knittl says, you should execute
`git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog` to get a list of objects (blobs or trees) and then read the objects with
`git cat-file -p <object hash>` until you find what you need.

For trees, you have to use git commands: `git read-tree`.

Comment: @Vivoconumxino, thanx for your answer. I've tried but couldn't find any blob objects.

Comment: You might see a list of hashes, unfortunately, for the other answers, this seems to be the only possibility