# Is there a reflog for the index?

Tags: git, git-index, git-reflog

I do not have a specific problem at hand, but I have encountered in the past some cases where I accidentally blew up my index, and wished I could go back the the previous state of a given file, which was indexed at some point.

Some example cases are :

```
$ git add <file>
# find out that I already had an indexed version of <file>,
# and that for some reason I shouldn't have added the extra modifications

$ git stash pop
# find out afterwards that I have a mix of "the index I had"
# and "the index in the stash"

$ git reset <typo>
# accidentally resetting the wrong file, or the whole directory
```

One could resort to digging through `git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782978/recover-files-that-were-added-to-the-index-but-then-removed-by-a-git-reset)), I was wondering if there was a more convenient way to do this.

**Question :**

Is there some kind of reflog for the index ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reflog contains entries for refs...not the index.

But, perhaps a workflow tweak is the answer here...(it was for me).

If working on something that will take more than 5-10 minutes, ***commit-as-you-go*** (and cleanup prior to pushing). Otherwise, *stage-as-you-go*.

The `index` is great...I use it all day long! But I only really use it if I know that I will be commiting within just a minute or two (basically an atomic workflow operation). This is because I am scared that I will do something stupid and blow away my index.

While I am working, every time I reach a little milestone I make a private commit that usually will not be pushed until I've had a chance to do some cleanup first. I keep on commiting as I work on that specific problem, usually amending.

Then, once I've actually reached a stable point where I want to create a public commit I squash (if needed) all my little wip commits together, give a nice commit message and push.

This gives the huge advantage of creating little breadcrumbs in my reflog if needed.

Here's my workflow:

```
# start work
git checkout -b featurea
# work
vim file.txt
# reach a little milestone
git commit -a -m "working on feature..."
# work some more
vim file.txt
# reach another little milestone
git commit -a --reuse-message=HEAD --amend
# work some more
vim file.txt
# another little milestone...
git commit -a --reuse-message=HEAD --amend
# finishing touches...
vim file.txt
# ok, done now, put everything back in working dir so I can review
git reset HEAD~
# decide what goes in this commit
# perhaps use `git add -p`
git add file.txt
# give a nice commit message (use editor)
git commit
# now merge to master and push with confidence!
```

This may seem like a lot of typing, but if you get good at flying on the shell (taking advantage of `set -o emacs` or `set -o vi` is a good way) then this approach becomes almost instant.

If what I'm working on truly is a very quick fix I will typically just use the stage-as-you-go approach, but anything longer than that I need the safety of populating my reflog as I go.

Comment: +1 on the workflow.  Also, for somewhat longer tasks (anything that may take more than a day, or sometimes even anything longer than a few hours), create local branches.  Git's branches are nearly free: they do take a bit of disk space but I find their most expensive resource is my own head space ("hm, I have `experiment1` through `experiment45`, great, now *what the heck was I experimenting with*?)...

Comment: @torek off topic - but when is your git book coming out? :-)

Comment: @Alok-- I got a full time job and work on it ground to a halt, alas!

Comment: @torek thanks for the message!  I can help with the menial parts, if needed :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no reflog for the index. you will have to work our way around as you figured out with the `git fsck` with or without the `--lost-found` flag to the command.

You can use the timestamp of the files (SHA-1) to "sort" the files by the creation date and have some basic reflog based upon file creation time.

Comment: For the sake of testing, I tried to look up all the `.git/objects/ab/cdef...` blobs returned by my `fsck --unreachable`. Some of the dangling blobs are not there, which probably means they are stored in pack files. Do you know a quick way to find the pack file a blob belongs to ?

Comment: I was looking for the modification date of the files. Do you have some other trick in mind to find the modification date of a blob ?